# Can we load a Chakra Ui Avatar from an image in the project folder?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, web-frontend, chakra-ui

I can't figure how to load an image from a project folder to use as a Chakra-UI Avatar.
The src attribute seems to only be able to take external links.
The component file I'm working on is located in the src/Components/ folder, the image I want to load is in the src/images folder.
Why doesn't this render my avatar, and is there a way to make it work?

```
<Avatar src={"../images/logo.png"} alt={"Logo"} size={2}></Avatar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using react, generally in React you can add images with two methods. You can click [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) to view more information.

```
import logo from '../images/logo.png';
<Avatar src={logo} alt={"Logo"} size={2}/>
```

The other method is to serve the files through the "public" folder and link it in your component. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/